# Ubuntu 16.04 - Ubuntu doesn't detect my discrete GPU and so Vulkan and OpenGL

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, graphics, vulkan

(I'm using an *unknown* model of Nvidia Geforce)

Because of that i have to use Intel's integrated Graphics Processing Unit. When i enumerate physical devices in Vulkan i can only see one physical device, and it is Intel Haswell Mobile. Ubuntu is not detect my GPU.

When i pass this to terminal:

```
sudo lshw -C video
```

I got this result:

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:43 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
```

I was installed the *nvidia-current* package. What is the problem? And what is the model of my GPU?

Comment: As that terminal output says: `product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]`. Are you sure it's enabled in BIOS?

Comment: You  can't see your BIOS settings without going into your BIOS settings (well, not easily at all). Why don't you want to reboot?

Comment: I reboot my computer. There is nothing related about GPU even.

Comment: Then try http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: Do i have to always purge and reinstall the drivers and applications? Is there another way? Ethernet connection is not limitless in my country. I do not want to waste it.

Comment: Nvidia-common is depreciated, go to the `additional-drivers` app and install the one it recommends.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package additional-drivers

Comment: It is an app, part of system settings, use GUI

Comment: @IbrahimIpek the NVIDIA driver is over 350MB. If you want it, you'll have to download it.

Comment: Okey, i downloading it.